# Testing Cloudant connection pool with JMeter

Tags: java, node.js, jmeter, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I made two apps (one with Java and one with NodeJS) connecting to a Bluemix instance of Cloudant and I am trying to test my connection pool settings.

With Java, I am using the java-cloudant library both with and without the OkHttp dependency. I believe using the default connection pool gives a max connection of 5. When using OkHttp, I am setting the max connections to 1, 5, 200, and 1000. Testing with 200, 500, 1000 threads in JMeter, I am getting the same results between using the default connection pool and using OkHttp with different max connection settings.

With NodeJS, I am using the nodejs-cloudant library and the results are similar to Java.

I am expecting my tests to be a lot faster with a larger number of max connections for the connection pool but it doesn't seem to be affecting my tests. Does anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, if connection pool is lower than the number of incoming requests the requests will be queuing up and performance will be lower. However I can see at least 2 scenarios when it will no be the case:

1. You are not really simulating 200, 500, etc. threads in JMeter. Depending on your configuration you may run into the situation when some threads have already finished their job and some have not even been yet started. Double check how many threads you really have using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener or equivalent chart of the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html). Check out JMeter Test Results: [Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) for detailed explanation of the common mistake.
2. Your application is not capable of processing that many requests, to wit you reached the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) of your system, so up to certain number of threads the throughput increases as you increase the number of virtual users, then there is the point of maximum performance called [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html), then throughput remains the same or even decreases. So check whether your application(s) have enough headroom to operate in terms of resources (RAM, CPU, Network, Disk) - you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this or use [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) to identify where your application is spending time.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will check with the two scenarios you listed when I get a chance and get back to you with results. 

I just realized why I'm not getting the results I was expecting for for example 5 max connections. In my app, I do a get document and then sleep for 5 seconds to simulate delay but I just realized that the 5 seconds sleep will not affect the connection to pool. I was expecting a total run time of 200 seconds for 200 threads and 5 max connections but it only took 38 seconds.